# Why is the first line longer?

Tags: python, text-files

i'm using python to read a txt document with:

```
f = open(path,"r")
for line in f:
    line = line.decode('utf8').strip()
    length = len(line)
    firstLetter = line[:1]
```

it seems to work, but the first line's length is always longer by... 1

for example:
the first line is "XXXX" where X denotes a chinese character
then length will be 5, but not 4
and firstLetter will be nothing

but when it goes to the second and after lines,it works properly

tks~

Comment: What's `ord(firstLetter)` get you?

Comment: it says 65279, what is that? it's not a normal character

Comment: It's the BOM (actually a zero-width no-break space here), as the answer below says. It looked like nothing was there because it's a nonprinting character.

Comment: u mean i've to delete it myself? if that,won't it cost more to judge if it's first line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a UTF-8 BOM at the start of your file. Don't faff about inspecting the first character. Instead of the `utf8` encoding, use the [utf_8_sig encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig) with either `codecs.open()` or `your_byte_string.decode()` ... this sucks up the BOM if it exists and you don't see it in your code.

```
>>> bom8 = u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')
>>> bom8
'\xef\xbb\xbf'
>>> bom8.decode('utf8')
u'\ufeff'
>>> bom8.decode('utf_8_sig')
u'' # removes the BOM
>>> 'abcd'.decode('utf_8_sig')
u'abcd' # doesn't care if no BOM
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are probably getting the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) as the first character on the first line.

Information about dealing with it is [here](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html)

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm in china so i can't open that site.i searched in google, it says EditPlus added a BOM to utf8 file. so i changed the setting to "always remove signature" but it didn't work

Comment: @MangMang, don't worry, that site invites you to do complicated pointless code (inspect the first character yourself). See my answer.